# Are the JOIN statements correct?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have SQL query:

```
SELECT count(*) as total 
FROM ossn_users as u 
JOIN ossn_entities as e ON e.owner_guid=u.guid 
JOIN ossn_entities_metadata as emd ON emd.guid=e.guid 
WHERE(e.type='user' AND e.subtype='gender' AND emd.value='male' AND
      last_activity > 1495178076 - 100);
```

On same database with same data it gives in MySQL correct answer 2 but in PostgreSQL gives error answer 0.

How to convert this MySQL statement to correct PostgreSQL statement ?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a standard ANSI SQL query to me. It should produce the same results in any RDBMS supporting ANSI SQL. Can you create a demo of the issue so that we are able to reproduce it?

Comment: Thanks for answer. What demo you mean?

Comment: Perhaps case sensitivity? Can you share sample data?

Comment: I mean some schema description and sample data that would help us reproduce the issue in PostgreSQL.

Comment: The statement is syntactically correct. However, string comparison is case-sensitive in Postgres. Maybe you have rows with `'Gender'` or 'Male'`?

Comment: Thanks for all. I am stisfied with yours answers that SQL statment is correct in PostgreSQL. I will investigate data if there is not diffrence anyway. Thank you very much good. guys.

Comment: `last_activity > 1495178076 - 100` is this an integer-based date computation?

Answer (score 0):

As per all the comments, a general advise would be to use `upper` or `lower` eg: `lower(e.type)='user' AND lower(e.subtype)='gender' AND lower(emd.value)='male'`

This way, you won't have to worry about case-sensitivity.

(ps: due to less reputation, can't comment)